# AJAX Post Dynamic JSON Object MVC mapping

Tags: json, ajax

I have a dynamic name/value pair that, I am passing as a JSON to the controller.

Example: Dynamic JSON Object generated using below JQuery

```
{"vehicles":[{"odometer_675552753":"73750","odometer_723646452":"68127""price_709725300":"22984","price_709725299":"22999"}]}


var vehicleData = { 
        vehicles : [] 
    };

var vehicles = {}; 
$('.firDataField').each(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("name");
     var value = $(this).val();
     vehicles[id]=value;
});
vehicleData.vehicles.push(vehicles);

$.ajax({
    url: 'SaveVehicles.html',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data:JSON.stringify(vehicleData),
    type: "POST",
    cache:false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){        
        hideAjaxLoader();
    },
    error : function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('tbody#tbodyVehicleSearchData').html(''); 
        hideLoading();
        showGenericErrorMessage(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown, "VehicleSearch");
    }
});


Controller:

@RequestMapping("/SaveVehicles.html")
public void
String saveVehicles(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "vehicles") String jsonVehicleObject,
        HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
        throws Exception{
    LOGGER.entry();

    System.out.println("json: " + jsonVehicleObject);
}
```

jsonVehicleObject is always null. I have tried using RequestBody with Vehicles as object type. But no use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `type: 'Post'` in AJAX, that means you need to add a Request type in Controller.

Try using this in controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public void 
String saveVehicles(..)
```

Use `httpPost` in the Method for define type of response.

Answer (score 0):

You use jackson.
Jackson Convert Java Object to / from JSON

You search jackson. :D

sample code.

(pom.xml)

```
<!-- Jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

(js)

```
var list = new Array();

list.push(Your data);

data = JSON.stringify(list);
$.ajax({
        url : "your url",
        type : 'POST',
        data : data,
        contentType : 'application/json',

        success : function(response) {

        },
        error : function(request, status, error) {

        }
});
```

(controller)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "your path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody List<TestModel> models) {


    return null; // break point, check model.
}
```

You create model.